# React inline styles error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Big fan of inline styles and decided to give it a try. I'm slowly getting the hang of it but I'm now stuck because I keep getting the "Unknown prop `styles` on <img> tag" error.

My code is as shown below:

```
render(){
    let imgUrl = 'http://mrmrs.io/images/0006.jpg';
    let divStyles = {
        backgroundImage:'url(" + imgUrl + ")',
        backgroundSize: 'cover'
    };
    return(
        <main class="cf w-100">
          <div class="fl w-50 w-third-m w-25-ns">
            <div class="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio--1x1">
              <img styles="{{divStyles}}"  class="db bg-center cover aspect-ratio--object" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>

    )
}
```

The simple stuff are always the ones that give me the most problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you use className instead of class when writing JSX?

Comment: change `class` to `className` and also when the `divStyles` is an object just use it as `style={divStyles}`

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried the above but now get "The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX."

Comment: Do I see correctly that you are defining an <img> without a src but with only a background-image? If so, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prop should be `style` not `styles`. And you need to define a `height` and a `width` to the `img` tag.

Hope this helps!

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
      let imgUrl = 'http://mrmrs.io/images/0006.jpg';
      let divStyles = {
          backgroundImage:'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
      };
      return(
          <main className="cf w-100">
            <div className="fl w-50 w-third-m w-25-ns">
              <div className="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio--1x1">
                <img style={divStyles}  className="db bg-center cover aspect-ratio--object" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>

      )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to change backgroundImage:'url(" + imgUrl + ")', to backgroundImage:'url(' + imgUrl + ')', and change styles to style and it worked.

Comment: @user3590911 That's goood!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to use the style object differently like `style={divStyles}` and not `styles="{{divStyles}}"` second you image will now be rendered since `'url("+ imgUrl + ")',` will be treated as a string and not rendered as `'url("http://mrmrs.io/images/0006.jpg")',`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    let imgUrl = 'http://mrmrs.io/images/0006.jpg';
    var url = 'url("' + imgUrl + '")'; 
    let divStyles = {
        backgroundImage:url,
        backgroundSize: 'cover'
    };
    return(
        <main class="cf w-100">
          <div class="fl w-50 w-third-m w-25-ns">
            <div class="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio--1x1">
              <img style={divStyles}  class="db bg-center cover aspect-ratio--object" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>

    )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with **{{}}** and **{}** in React.

With your code, it is not required to have double braces **{{}}** because the `divStyles` is already an object.

Try the below one, should work.

```
<img styles="{divStyles}"  class="db bg-center cover aspect-ratio--object" />
```

The above could be written as shown below

```
<img styles="{{
      backgroundImage:'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
  }}"  class="db bg-center cover aspect-ratio--object" />
```